# array of string output is a clover symbol

Tags: c

No matter what the 5th input the output was clover symbol, program purpose was to align right the inputs:
EDIT
im not using scanf(%[\^n],a[i]), the output was horrible, using gets instead

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char a[6][50];
    int i;
    for (i=1;i<=5;i++)
    {
        printf("insert name%d :\n",i);
        gets(a[i]);
    }
    for (i=1;i<=5;i++)
    {
        printf("%d%25s\n",i,a[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Example output:

```
1         far cry
2        iron man
3 new super mario
4         program
5        "clover"
```

Comment: Btw, indexing starts at 0.

Comment: yes ik can use i=0;i<5;i++

Comment: @pzaenger Yes but he is doing it the VB way, the 0 index is never used. Array is 6 units length so he can reach a[5]...

Comment: You should always check the return code from scanf. Do not just assume it will work.

Comment: Isn't there a thing about flushing the input between two scanfs ?

Comment: `gets()` shouldn't be used because it has unavoidable risk of buffer overrun.

Comment: so what should i use to get user input ?, i need to get space, normal scanf will not read it

Comment: The simplest approach here is probably `fgets`.

Comment: [Works for me](http://ideone.com/szgXqg) - are you sure you didn't enter a long string (> 49 chars) for one of the inputs ?

Comment: @PaulR im surely not, what makes me confused is all 1st to 4th output was okay. why the last one isnt working ?

Comment: Actually, `gets()` is no longer part of the language. As in, officially. Let's hope the compiler maintainers give it the toss soon.

Comment: The output is not in sync with the code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using your code, I got strange chars on output as you mentioned.

So, I made some fixes on your code and now I think it works properly.

```
#include <unistd.h>
int main(void)
{
    char a[6][50];
    int i, r;
    for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        printf("insert name%d :\n", i);
        r = read(STDIN_FILENO, a[i], 49);
        a[i][r] = '\0';
    }
    for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        printf("%d%25s\n", i, a[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Avoid to use deprecated functions in your code.

You need to ensure that after reading from `stdin`, your buffer is going to get the `null` terminator right after the last position written in buffer.

Comment: wow idk what inside unistd.h library, but why there is an extra line ?

Comment: unistd in this case was included to to allow to use the read funcion, as well as the STDIN_FILENO symbol. 

You can get more information in [link](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/unistd.h.html)

If you mean this extra line:
a[i][r] = '\0'; 

It is to ensure you are putting the null terminator in your string.

Comment: i mean like there is total 10 line as output with extra blank line. actually this is a school task using autograder, so output needs to be exactly the same. TY anyway, this works. well ill check whats inside unistd.h though